# Remove multiple vnet peers azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, vnet

I have a requirement to remove and recreate 24 peers from two separate VNETS.

2 different subscriptions, 2 different VNETs. the peering all in the same vnet -

12 in PRD

12 in DEV

I am hoping to automate this process. What is the best approach to accomplish this? The main goal is to automate and make the script/template portable.

AZ CLI, ARM Template, PowerShell?

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Let me know if my understading is correct or not you are looking to remove or create the VNET peering's for both the subscription for example VNET-A in subscriptionA is peered with other VNET's present in subscriptionA and the same VNETB in SubscriptionB?
VNETA and VNETB are not peered with each other?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could use Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI to remove the vnet peering.

Azure PowerShell: [`Remove-AzVirtualNetworkPeering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/remove-azvirtualnetworkpeering?view=azps-6.6.0)

```
Remove-AzVirtualNetworkPeering -Name "myVnet1TomyVnet2" -VirtualNetworkName "myVnet" -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup"
```

Azure CLI: [`az network vnet peering delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vnet/peering?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_vnet_peering_delete)

```
az network vnet peering delete -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVnet1ToMyVnet2 --vnet-name MyVnet1
```